# Laravel view more link pass id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello I am using laravel 5 to display a 20 column csv from my database, I have a foreach loop displaying 5 of the 20 columns in a table and then a view more button to take you to another page with a table showing all the information of that particular row depending on the id.

My question is how do I pass the id to the other page so I can do another foreach loop to display the rest of the info? I have it so when you hover over the link it's display the id. I know this is vague so if you could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated as I'm not home at the minute so I can't post my code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called `pagination` and lucky for you Laravel has made a beautiful function to make this easier documented at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination.